# Text garbling in compiling Java at Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

I'm a university student in Japan, and I can't speak English well, but let me ask one question.

I attempted to start Java and installed Java jdk1.8.0_171 including javac and java.
Then, I set PATH at Windows10, and succeeded in compiling one java file.

However, when I attempted another file, Cygwin showed me an error message and it was broken, so called text garbling.

I don't mind that language in Cygwin will be English, so please teach me how to solve this problem.

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image]

Comment: Well, you have a compilation problem in `test.java` at line 16. I would guess you are calling a method `normRand` from a `static` context (most likely the `main` method). Without the code, hard to say but this is a problem with a `static` context.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I could improve my script just now! ...but from now on I want to check my script by error message. If possible, please tell me how to solve the problem of text garbling. Sorry for my slow typing...

Comment: Ok, so we ignore the code completely ? Is it only a problem with `javac`? I would guess cygwin use an encoding and javac another.